# Is Ubuntu's handling of other internal drives safe?

Tags: drive

When ever I restart or shutdown the computer, I have to click on the drive and it takes a few minutes until the drive is technically "mounted".

Is it safe? does this means that every time the computer is restarted the internal drives are un-mounted and re-mounted? For example, when I first start the computer and I go to `System Monitor` and click `File Systems` the other drivers are not shown. After I click on the drive folder, it shows up there.

Isn't that a potential danger to the hard drive and the data?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is safe.  The way Ubuntu is designed, the default is to only automatically mount the Ubuntu partition.  Whether you are trying to access other partitions on the same drive, or another drive, they are not set to mount on startup.  This is normal, and mounting them manually does not pose any risk to the data, nor does shutting down your system unmount them in an unsafe manner.

That said, there are ways to make it automatically mount other drives on startup, so that you will see them from the moment you log on.  Several of these ways are examined at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions That said, unless it is a major inconvenience to you, there is no reason to set them up to automatically mount and if you are unsure of yourself (like if you are new to Ubtuntu) you may not want to risk making mistakes that could be irreversible.